# iOS - Sort NSDictionay keys by sub value

Tags: ios, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a NSDictionary with currency-codes as keys and as values another NSDictionary inside containing a NSString (currency name) + a NSArray (list of coins):

[image: Plist]

The goal is to get a NSArray with currency-keys (AED, ARS, ...), sorted by name-value inside.

I know how to sort by keys and values, but can't figure out how to sort by the a value inside a NSDictionary inside a NSDictionary.

The following only gives me a sorted NSArray with the values, but I loose the keys:

```
NSMutableArray *dictValues = [[self.currencyDict allValues] mutableCopy];

    [dictValues sortUsingComparator: (NSComparator)^(NSDictionary *a, NSDictionary *b)
     {
         NSString *key1 = [a objectForKey: @"name"];
         NSString *key2 = [b objectForKey: @"name"];

         return [key1 compare: key2];
     }
     ];
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Dictionaries can't be sorted. And the array you have in `dictValues` containers the inner dictionaries so the currency code keys are lost as soon as you call `all Values`. What is it that you really want to have at the end?

Comment: In the end I want an array with the keys sorted by the content of the name-key within each Dictionary. But I think I will follow user3386109's suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to convert a `dictionary of dictionaries` into an `array of dictionaries` without losing the key, the first step is to put the key  into the dictionary.  In other words, you need to convert this

```
Root
  AED
    name     "some name"
    objects  ...
  ARS
    name     "other name"
    objects  ...
```

to this

```
Root
  AED
    name     "some name"
    objects  ...
    key      "AED"
  ARS
    name     "other name"
    objects  ...
    key      "ARS"
```

and then call `allValues` and sort the resulting array.

Comment: Okay, so I need to have the key twice (redundant) to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, when you call `allValues` the redundant key will be lost, and you will be left with only the key in the sub-dictionaries.

Comment: No, he is saying. Put the keys of the dictionaries into the individual dictionaries. And then pull them out into an array. Now instead of a dictionary of dictionaries. You have an array of dictionaries. And you can use the key that you save as a way to sort the array.